# Stored procedure that counts all users where their membership is about to expire

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that needs to count all users where their membership is about to expire, the rule is that the membership expires a year after subscribing, so I want to count all users where their membership expiration date is reaching the current date but I need to count the users that their expiration date is at least a month before the current date.

I am using SQL Server.

My stored proc is like this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gp_get_cpd_membership_reaching_expiration]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS

--EXEC [gp_get_cpd_membership_reaching_expiration]

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT COUNT(a.userId) AS MembershipAlmostExpiredUsers
    FROM cpd_services_bureau a 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), a.membership_expiry_date) <= 60
END
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and desired output ?

Comment: Thanks @Sergey, so basically if the membership date was **2020**-03-09 07:08:43.787 then the expiration date would be **2021**-03-09 07:08:43.787, so I need to somehow get the users that have an expiration date that is near 2021-03-09 but the case would be to remind them a month before today's date which would be 2021-**02**-09 07:08:43.787

Comment: A simple google will show you how to build such a query... its very common

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I have added screenshots of my table structure and the membership column

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data or errors - use formatted text.

Comment: That is my SP so I am having issues with the WHERE clause

Comment: *where their membership expiration date is reaching the current date but I need to count the users that their expiration date is at least a month before the current date* - these seem to be in disagreement. an expiration date that is at least a month before the current date is an expiration date from a month ago to the infinite future. What you actually seem to want is **members who were created between 12 months ago and 11 months ago**, though your table has an expiry date column and a created column so it's not really clear which you want to use. you've highlighted Created in your screenshot

Comment: @LeeneshKolanda please stop putting code in comments. Dale already asked you to edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to base on users created between 12 months ago and 11 months ago (and hence have been a member for between 11 and 12 months) it's

```
SELECT COUNT(a.userId) AS MembershipAlmostExpiredUsers 
FROM cpd_services_bureau a 
WHERE a.date_created BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -12, getdate()) AND DATEADD(month, -11, getdate())
```

If it's based on an expiry date column correctly set at the time of creation it's

```
SELECT COUNT(a.userId) AS MembershipAlmostExpiredUsers 
FROM cpd_services_bureau a 
WHERE a.membership_expiry_date BETWEEN getdate() AND DATEADD(month, 1, getdate())
```

Always seek to avoid manipulating table data in a where clause (do not call functions on table data in a where clause)

---

There's a small thing to mention with BETWEEN that it includes the end date. If this is a problem for you (for example if your dates are in days, and you fin your query is running `BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and  '2021-02-01'` and hence including february dates you do not want, you can either swap to a form like `a.membership_expiry_date >= getdate() AND a.membership_expiry_date < DATEADD(month, 1, getdate())` using less than.. or you can come back a second on your end date, like `a.membership_expiry_date BETWEEN getdate() AND DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, getdate()))` - don't do this if your times are datetime2 and have milliseconds, of course

Comment: Thank you so much Caius, that is perfect, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @LeeneshKolanda, please mark it as answer. So, it will be helpful for others in future.